# Model binding comma separated query string parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

How can I bind query string parameter that is comma separated value

```
http://localhost/Action?ids=4783,5063,5305
```

to a controller action expecting a list?

```
public ActionResult Action(List<long> ids)
{
    return View();
}
```

**Note!** `ids` in the controller action must a list (or something IEnumerable based), so `string ids` is not accepted as an answer because these parameters are passed to many actions and parsing string to an array would add unwanted noise.

Comment: You need to create custom model binder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archils answer gave some ideas how to implement my own model binder. I was able to slightly simplify the source code as there wasn't need for very generic CSV support. Instead of setting the received data to `List<int>` I am putting it to the class.

**Model binder**

```
public class FarmModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(FarmModel))
        {
            var newBindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
            {
                ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(
                () => CreateFarmModel(controllerContext, bindingContext),
                typeof(FarmModel)
                ),
                ModelState = bindingContext.ModelState,
                ValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            };

            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, newBindingContext);
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

    private FarmModel CreateFarmModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var farmsIds = new List<int>();

        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("farmData");
        if(value != null && value.AttemptedValue != null)
        {
            var array = value.AttemptedValue.Split(new [] {','});
            foreach (var s in array)
            {
                int result;
                if(int.TryParse(s, out result))
                {
                    farmsIds.Add(result);
                }
            }
        }
        return new FarmModel() { FarmIds = farmsIds };
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class FarmModel
{
    public IEnumerable<int> FarmIds { get; set; }
}
```

**Adding of the custom binder**

```
System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(FarmModel), new FarmModelBinder());
```

Answer (score 35):

Here's my improved version of Nathan Taylor’s solution used in archil's answer.

1. Nathan’s binder could only bind sub-properties of complex models,
   while mine can also bind individual controller arguments.
2. My binder also gives you correct handling of empty parameters, by returning an
   actual empty instance of your array or IEnumerable.

To wire this up, you can either attach this to an individual Controller argument:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(CommaSeparatedModelBinder))]
```

…or set it as the global default binder in Application_Start in global.asax.cs:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CommaSeparatedModelBinder();
```

In the second case it will try and handle all IEnumerables and fall back to ASP.NET MVC standard implementation for everything else.

Behold:

```
public class CommaSeparatedModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo ToArrayMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToArray");

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        return BindCsv(bindingContext.ModelType, bindingContext.ModelName, bindingContext)
                ?? base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

    protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        return BindCsv(propertyDescriptor.PropertyType, propertyDescriptor.Name, bindingContext)
                ?? base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
    }

    private object BindCsv(Type type, string name, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (type.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable).Name) != null)
        {
            var actualValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(name);

            if (actualValue != null)
            {
                var valueType = type.GetElementType() ?? type.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();

                if (valueType != null && valueType.GetInterface(typeof(IConvertible).Name) != null)
                {
                    var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(valueType));

                    foreach (var splitValue in actualValue.AttemptedValue.Split(new[] { ',' }))
                    {
                            if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(splitValue))
                                list.Add(Convert.ChangeType(splitValue, valueType));
                    }

                    if (type.IsArray)
                        return ToArrayMethod.MakeGenericMethod(valueType).Invoke(this, new[] { list });
                    else
                        return list;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this model binder handle an `IEnumerable<Guid>` type? My implementation seems to be ignoring any `Guid` bindings.

Comment: @pate nope, won't work with Guids, they don't implement IConvertible

Comment: I had to modify it slightly to use with an enum i am using. Not sure if I did it in the best way, but where you add the value to the list `list.Add(Convert.ChangeType(splitValue, valueType));` I added check for my type of enum `if (valueType.Name == "Enumtype")` then added the appropriate enum to the list without the `Convert.ChangeType()`

Comment: An update I'd make to this class. Give it a constructor that takes an array of chars and use this in the `split` method, then inherit and use a parameterless constructor to pass in the split characters to create delimiters for commas, semicolons etc.

If you are using it via `global.asax.cs` you can pass in your preferred list of chars, however you're likely going to be using this as an attribute via `typeof` which is why you need the inheritance.

Comment: To further the comment left by Ben, I wouldn't handle arrays this way, that requires hard coding their names. The much simpler and more robust method is to check to see if the property is an Enum using valueType.IsEnum and attempting to parse it using Enum.Parse which will handle both the string name and the integer value. Maybe some error handling for if the enum value isn't found?

Answer (score 25):

Default model binder expects simple type lists to be in the format

```
name=value&name=value2&name=value3
```

To use builtin binding, you should change your query string to

```
Action?ids=4783&ids=5063&ids=5305
```

Or create custom model binder. You may take a look at [following article](http://blog.nathan-taylor.net/2011/11/comma-separated-values-model-binder.html) (code from there)

```
public class CommaSeparatedValuesModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo ToArrayMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToArray");

    protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable).Name) != null)
        {
            var actualValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);

            if (actualValue != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(actualValue.AttemptedValue) && actualValue.AttemptedValue.Contains(","))
            {
                var valueType = propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.GetElementType() ?? propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();

                if (valueType != null && valueType.GetInterface(typeof(IConvertible).Name) != null)
                {
                    var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(valueType));

                    foreach (var splitValue in actualValue.AttemptedValue.Split(new[] { ',' }))
                    {
                        list.Add(Convert.ChangeType(splitValue, valueType));
                    }

                    if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.IsArray)
                    {
                        return ToArrayMethod.MakeGenericMethod(valueType).Invoke(this, new[] { list });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return list;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Taken from [my answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

I will show you here a very simple custom model binder I have just written (and tested in **.Net Core 2.0**):

My model binder:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue; // get the value as string

        var model = value?.Split(",");
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

My model (and notice, **only one property has my custom model binder annotation**):

```
public class CreatePostViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = nameof(ContentText))]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = ValidationErrors.MinLength)]
    public string ContentText { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(BinderType = typeof(CustomModelBinder))]
    public IEnumerable<string> Categories { get; set; } // <<<<<< THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE INTERESTER IN

    #region View Data
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string TitlePlaceHolder { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

What it does is: it receives some text like "aaa,bbb,ccc", and converts it into array, and return it to the ViewModel.

I hope that helps.

DISCLAIMER: I am not an expert in model binders writing, I have learn that 15 minutes ago, and I found your question (with no helpful answer), so I tried to help. This is a very basic model binder, some improvements are surely required. I learned how to write it from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) page.