# Auto convert specific data type from c# to client

Tags: c#, types, controller, type-conversion

Is there any way to set globally rule for example in global.asax in C# to automatically convert and change specific data type to another data type?

For example automatically every property with Int64 or Long data type convert to the string **when it is passing from Controller to the Client**??

I know I can do that with defining Convert method but I think it is not good idea.

Thank you

Comment: I think you can use ModelBinding, use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584573/model-binding-comma-separated-query-string-parameter