# Comma Separated Values on a Net 6 Minimal Api parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Usings Net 6 Minimal API I have the following route:

```
builder.MapGet("posts", async ([FromQuery] IEnumerable<Int32> postsIds) => {
});
```

The parameters `postsIds` contains the `ids` of posts to be loaded, e.g., "1, 3, 5".

I get the following error when running the application:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll: 'No public static bool IEnumerable.TryParse(string, out IEnumerable) method found for postsIds.

So I created the following:

```
public class CommaSeparatedValues<T> {

  public IEnumerable<T> Values { get; set; } = new List<T>();

  public static Boolean TryParse(String? value, IFormatProvider? provider, out CommaSeparatedValues<T>? commaSeparatedValues) {

    IEnumerable<T>? values = value?.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries).Cast<T>();

    if (values is null) {
      commaSeparatedValues = null;
      return false;
    }

    commaSeparatedValues = new CommaSeparatedValues<T> { Values = values };
    return true;

  }
```

And changed the endpoint to:

```
builder.MapGet("posts", async ([FromQuery] CommaSeparatedValues<Int32> postsIds) => {
});
```

Does this make sense? Can I improve / simplify this approach? Or this is the way?

Comment: I don't know if you like this method, but if you repeat query parameters they will come into the controller as an array: `?id=1&id=3&id=5`

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. Also `.Cast<T>()` will not work cause you can't cast `string` to `int`.

Comment: @Crowcoder I know. But what would be type of the parameter in my endpoint method? Array of int?

Comment: why not send all comma separated values in one parameter and use custom model binder to fill a list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Model binding comma separated query string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584573/model-binding-comma-separated-query-string-parameter) Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49910078/2343086

Answer (score -1):

According to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-binding), so I test your code in my side:

Pls note this line `var trimmedValue = value?.TrimStart('(').TrimEnd(')');` and `CommaSeparatedValues<string> postsIds`. Per my test I found when using `CommaSeparatedValues<Int32> postsIds` it will appear error message below because it can't execute `.Cast<T>()` successfully.

[image]

```
app.MapGet("posts", (CommaSeparatedValues<string> postsIds) => {
    return postsIds;
});

public class CommaSeparatedValues<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Values { get; set; } = new List<T>();

    public static Boolean TryParse(String? value, IFormatProvider? provider, out CommaSeparatedValues<T>? commaSeparatedValues)
    {
        {
            // Format is "(12.3,10.1)"
            var trimmedValue = value?.TrimStart('(').TrimEnd(')');
            IEnumerable<T>? values = trimmedValue?.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries).Cast<T>();

            if (values is null)
            {
                commaSeparatedValues = null;
                return false;
            }

            commaSeparatedValues = new CommaSeparatedValues<T> { Values = values };
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

By the way if you can accept to use this instead?

```
app.MapGet("posts", async ([FromQuery(Name = "postsIds")] string postsIds) =>
{
    List<string> list = postsIds.Split(",").ToList(); 
    return postsIds;
});
```